# Instagram API | Publish content

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

Is it possible to use the "publish content" features in test mode ?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/guides/content-publishing/

Actually only beta tester can use this feature, but I would like to start developping...

When will be this feature available ?

Thank you